# What changes are required in the project if we want to change the bundle ID of our app in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I wish to change my bundle ID and before doing that I just wanted to know, what will be the changes that I will have to make in my project and Firebase console.
Will I need to download a new google-services.json file?